# Issues installing Ubuntu in a HP ZBook 17 G3

Tags: boot

I have an HP ZBook 17 G3. Specs are listed below to assist.

I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday and ran into a few issues.

Upon boot from a USB it would hang at the splash screen with 5 dots. The 5th dot never lit up. Disabled fast boot, and secure boot and got it to boot up into the "try linux" option trackpad worked. But mouse buttons and keyboard didn't work, neither did plugging-in keyboard or mouse.

Tried going back and doing install seeing as I thought it might go this time. And it would hang again. I don't mind going to an older version and then upgrading. I don't mind trying a different Linux distro either.

- I7 - 6820HQ
- 16GB RAM
- NVIDIA Quadro M4000M
- 256GB SSD - 1TB HDD

Comment: What you need is: 1. Making sure it's booting in UEFI mode and 2. When at the menu with "Try Ubuntu" selected press "e" to edit and then add `nomodeset` in the same line where " quiet splash" is. This will load a safe graphics mode, don't worry about the low resolution. Install. Do the same in the first boot and then install Nvidia graphics drivers.